# Selenium JAVA : How to validate a frequently changing data in the front end?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dynamic

The website that I am automating has a data which is something like,

"Delivery Sep 06 Thursday"

The date keeps changing everyday. I now have to validate it's presence and the message format. 
Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Post relevant HTML Code

Comment: The data comes in from an API .

Comment: Yes, but is still displayed on HTML page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. If you know what's a formula behind expected date (for example: always same day; always 3 days from now, or even some more complicated rules), then your test can generate expected date much like the site does, and validate that date displayed on the site is the same as your expected date.
2. If you don't know the formula, it's too complicated, or changes too often, then you can validate 3 things:

   - That date is displayed in proper format (e.g. you could check that its format is `Delivery MMM DD EEEE`)
   - Date and day of the week match (e.g. check that `Sep 06` is indeed Thursday)
   - Date is within acceptable range (e.g. +/- week from current date, or whatever makes sense)

Those are general rules. If you want a more specific advice, please post HTML code, and some logic behind expected dates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public String getCurrentDate() {
    //Delivery Sep 06 Thursday
    String format = "MMM dd EEEEE";
    SimpleDateFormat formatCurrentDate = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
    Calendar userDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    return formatCurrentDate.format(userDate.getTime());
}

public void checkDeliveryDate() throws Exception {
    String searchString = "Delivery " + getCurrentDate();
    driver.isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[.='"+searchString+"'])"));
}
```